# FreeNAS (11.2-U7) how to repair degraded boot pool that is on two USB sticks?

Tags: boot, freebsd, zfs, freenas

I have a Dell R230 which I've setup a few years ago with FreeNAS (installed version is 11.2-U7)

The boot partition was installed on a mirrored pool on two 32GB USB sticks.

- /dev/da9p2 - SanDisk Ultra Fit USB 3.1 Flash Drive
- /dev/da10p2 - Samsung Bar Plus USB 3.1 Flash Drive

A while ago I started to get a warning when booting the server:

info
Boot Pool Status Is DEGRADED: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error. An attempt was made to correct the error. Applications are unaffected.

The Boot Pool Status looked like this:
[image]

I removed the da10 device (Samsung Bar Plus) since that one showed 0 bytes written to /read from and rebootet, getting the same Boot Pool Status, but with /dev/da10p2 now reading INVAL instead of ONLINE.
I clicked the three dots right of /dev/da10p2 and selected 'detach', and now I'm seeing this BootPool Status:
[image]
So, the 'mirror' is gone and only /dev/da9p2 is still visible.
Clicking the three dots right of /dev/da9p2 only gives me a 'replace' option and clicking the three dots right of freenas-boot gives me an 'attach' option.

I got a second 32GB SanDisk Ultra Fit (so the same I hope as the one that is in /dev/da9p2, diskinfo -v reports exact same media size and sector size, but different Disk descriptors) - but when I try to attach it to freenas-boot, I'm getting the following gpart error:
[image]
`[EFAULT] Command '('gpart', 'create', '-s', 'gpt', '/dev/da10')' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

if I try to manually execute `gpart create -s gpt /dev/da10` I'm getting `gpart: geom 'da10': File Exists`

How can I get back to a mirrored boot pool using the second SanDisk Ultra Fit?

Comment: Why did you remove the only ONLINE device in that pool?  ONLINE=GOOD, DEGRADED=BAD.  You should have removed the DEGRADED device (the da9pt disk device, not the `mirror` vdev).   Dunno if it will work, but the only thing I can think of to try is to power off, physically remove the da9pt drive, plug da10p2 back in, and see if it'll boot.

Comment: because there were zero bytes read/written from that one, so I suspected that it's the one labelled 'DEGRADED' which it booted from. Since it still can boot after removing the one saying 'ONLINE', I suspect that has to be correct

Comment: If that doesn't work and if the boot pool contained only the OS and config info, then you should be able to re-install on a new boot pool, configure it as needed, and import your data pool(s) into the new freenas system.

Comment: @cas I currently can still boot - I just don't know how to mirror back to a new USB stick. I have no additional USB slots available, so if I remove the other SanDisk Ultra Fit, then I cannot boot FreeNas at all anymore

Comment: if those numbers were directly from the output of `zpool status` (and they seem to be), then they're error counts.  12170 read errors, 15068 write errors, 1904 checksum errors.  i.e. dead/dying drive.

Comment: If you have access to a root shell on your freenas box, you could maybe try `zpool attach -f -s freenas-boot /dev/da9pt2 /dev/da10pt2` (the new da10 drive, not the original one you removed - don't erase or write anything on that one!!!).  The `-f` option is to force attaching the new dev (I suspect zfs is complaining about attach a mirror to a degraded device), and the `-s` is for fast sequential resync of the mirror.  see `man zpool-attach`.  Even if this works, there will be data loss - da9pt has LOTS of read, write, and checksum errors.  It's well on it's way to dying, replace it ASAP.

Comment: The reason I say don't do anything to the original da10 drive is that it may have the only complete, non-degraded copy of the data that's supposed to be on your `freenas-boot` pool. You don't want to do anything that could lose that. (but it'll probably be difficult to extract anything from it - you did `detach` it from the pool, after all.  if it doesn't just boot up by itself, it'll probably take a real expert with a lot of experience debugging zfs pools to recover).

Comment: @cas I removed da9 and inserted da10 just to see if I could boot from it, but FreeNAS doesn't boot from it from either USB port. From da9 however it can boot, independently of which USB port I plug it into. I will now try your `zpool attach` command

Comment: hope that works.  btw, if/when you get this back up and running (or just re-install your freenas-boot pool) I recommend sending a nightly snapshot to your main data pool.  that way you'll at least have a backup you can restore from in case of future disaster.